# Is it true that if $M : \forall \alpha . \left( \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \right)$ is a closed term then $M = \Lambda \alpha. \lambda x^{\alpha} . x$?

Tags: lambda-calculus

In system F, is every closed term $M$, which is of $\forall \alpha . \left( \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \right)$, $\alpha \beta \eta$-equivalent to $\Lambda \alpha. \lambda x^{\alpha} . x$?

I have believed that this is true and have tried to prove it by using the equation

> $\forall \alpha. \forall \beta. \forall f^{\alpha \rightarrow \beta} . \forall x^{\alpha} . M \beta \left( f x \right) = f \left( M \alpha x \right)$

, which *I think* is a consequence of [theorems for Free](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf), but couldn't prove it.

Thanks to read my question.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. It does have a proof using theorems for Free or logical relations/parametricity. Try building the appropriate relation. Amal Ahmed’s lectures in OPLSS does a good job of explaining the setup.

Comment: Let $y : \beta$ be arbitrary, and replace $f$ with $\lambda z^{\alpha} . y$. Then $M \beta y = y$.